# Experimental information: is momentum conserved?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, conservation-laws, home-experiment

[image]

Could I say that it is conserved during the time, or instead there is a slight decrease?

Comment: Looks like you have a measured angular momentum as a function of time, but could you explain a bit more what it is you did?

Comment: It is related to the movement of a mass in a central potential. We tried to make a circular path.. but instead the movement was reduced to two different radius.

Comment: What does your measurement setup look like and what is the uncertainty of each measurement (I do not see error bars)?

Comment: My aim is to analise the conservation of energy in order to detect external forces or assume they were negligible.

Comment: the error would be aproximately +-4000;  (in the "y" direccion of course)

Comment: I analise the movement of a oscilation. It lasted 2 seconds. The mass was linked to a spring and the friction force with the table is almost null.

Comment: Suggest do a linear correlation test like Pearson coefficient. That would be very simple. You have a good sample size. Recommend you ask the guys at http://stats.stackexchange.com/ because this is a statistics question.